# Integer solutions to $x^w+\sqrt[w]{y}=wz$?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a method that I could find as many values as I want for variables $w, x, y, z$ so that the equation $x^w+\sqrt[w]{y}=wz$ satisfies?

I found $(2,3,9,6)$ ; $(4,2,0,4)$ ; $(-2,1,1,-1)$ and $(3,1,8,1)$, but I'm sure there are much more than this.

**EDIT:** I forgot to add that I want solutions so that a value doesn't repeat more than twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any tuple $(w, x, y, z)$ satisfying the equation and any integer $a$, the tuple  $(w,ax,a^{w^2}y,a^wz)$ also satisfies the equation.

Comment: Wow this is probably the best answer.

Comment: How do you figure this out?

Comment: We notice that $z$ only appears on the right hand side, and $x$ and $y$ only appear on the left hand side.  Thus, if we can adjust $x$ and $y$ in such a way that the new left side is a multiple of the old one, we can multiply $z$ by that same multiple.  Taking a guess at replacing $x$ by $ax$, we see that the first term on the left becomes $a^wx^w$, so we want the second term to be $a^w\sqrt[w] y =\sqrt[w]{a^{w^2}y}$.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just let $x=2w,y=w^w,z=1+2^ww^{w-1}$ for any integer $w$.

Comment: I'm sorry I should've pointed this out. I want solutions so that a value doesn't repeat more than twice.

Comment: And how do I find this out?

Comment: Edited, does that work?

Comment: How do I find this out?

Comment: more especially, how did you figure that out in 1 minute

Comment: Well for example when $w=3$ you have $(w,x,y,z)=(3,6,27,73)$

Comment: Change $2$ into a parameter as well, & $y=(kw)^{w}$, for an even more general solution.

Comment: But how did you figure out to let $x=2w, y=w^w$ and so on? I want to know so I don't have to ask another question if I have a similar problem.

Comment: @KKZiomek Since you want integer solutions, you know $y$ is a power of $w$ and furthermore $w$ divides $x$ and $y$ (roughly speaking). So you plug in $x=2w,y=w^w$ and $z$ is just what's left over.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary integers $x, w, z$ such that $w \ge 0$ and either $w$ is odd or $wz \ge x^w$, just take 
$$ y = (wz - x^w)^w $$